# SharePoint Online list view threshold error in a lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, list-view-threshold

I am facing an issue with lookup column in the list forms due to list view threshold limit (5000 items).

The parent list is having more than 5000 items. Hence the lookup field is not getting displayed in the forms and showing a message like below.

> "This is a lookup column that displays data from another list that
>   currently exceeds the List View Threshold defined by the administrator
>   (5000)."

I have tried indexing this lookup column and some of the columns in the Parent list but the issue still persists.

Is there any workaround for this issue so that lookup column gets displayed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: From the error, it appears your issue is that the LOOKUP list has more than 5000 items. Not your PARENT list. The purpose of a lookup list is to give the user options, such as "Category", or "State". Lookup lists should NOT have thousands of options. They would be of no use to your user. I don't know the specifics of your use case, but I think you should rethink how your data is arranged.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently come across this same issue and from what I've found, there is no solution other than removing records from your parent list so it's under 5,000 items.  There is this [idea on the SharePoint User Voice for removing the threshold](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/8463457-remove-the-list-view-threshold-5000-by-default), and an update from MS states that "Being able to index/sort/filter by lookup column types (like person, lookup or managed metadata columns) without being throttled." is on their backlog.  I would suggest voting the issue up.

@CigarDoug, when you have a parent/child solution setup, this is likely scenario. There isn't a way to rethink the solution.  Microsoft needs to figure out how to make their applications work without these types of limitations.  Plenty of other cloud software solutions have figured it out.